# Setting new state can change the data's color attribute, but not image

Tags: javascript, json, reactjs, dynamic, react-hooks

I want to make a small app, where user can choose car/motocycle in what color they like.

I am almost there to achieve it, but unfortunately, when I click the color button, it changes only the written name of the color, but not the preview image of that car/motocycle in that specific chosen color.

I am using the same logic, so I don't know why it does work in one part, but not the other.

**Current behaviour example:**
Pick red color of the car 1 -> default color name will be overwritten, but the image will be missing, instead of changing it to the correct image of car in red color.

I created sandbox of the current behaviour:

https://codesandbox.io/s/festive-framework-9u75w?file=/src/App.js

Comment: check my answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I changed your sandbox a little bit

I try to find image inside the `colors` object. This means that `image` property of car/motorcycle is not needed anymore.

```
                  <CarInfo
                    key={item.id}
                    image={
                      item.car.colors[item.car["selected"].toLowerCase()]
                        ? item.car.colors[
                            item.car["selected"].toLowerCase()
                          ].image
                        : null
                    }
                    name={item.car.name}
                    color={item.car["selected"]}
                  />
```

and

```
                  <MotocycleInfo
                    key={item.id}
                    image={
                      item.motocycle.colors[
                        item.motocycle["selected"].toLowerCase()
                      ]
                        ? item.motocycle.colors[
                            item.motocycle["selected"].toLowerCase()
                          ].image
                        : null
                    }
                    name={item.motocycle.name}
                    color={item.motocycle["selected"]}
                  />
```

[sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/epic-leaf-22g72)

Code can be shortened if e.g. you need to show by default the first image, so

```
            image={
              item.car.colors[
                item.car["selected"]
                  ? item.car["selected"].toLowerCase()
                  : 0
              ].image
            }
```

Comment: That works @Apostolos, thank you! Altough I am a little bit lost in logic this time. But it does what it should, is that a good practice to do it in such a way?

Comment: it depends. if you need a smaller payload of a json object, then you go this way. if you dont mind and you can put extra props, you can just replace the one line that tausif suggested and this works too. it's all about how you want to handle your data. i prefer not to duplicate info if possible :)

Comment: updated my answer. if for example you want to show be default the first color image, then you can change your property like i did.

Answer (score 0):

Just replace below single line in **handleColorCar()** method.

```
 // Your code   
 changedItem.motocycle.image = e.target.value;
    
 // Working code
 changedItem.car.image = selectedData.car.colors[e.target.value.toLowerCase()].image;
```